# how to append data in xml using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have below script which will create xml with data.

======================================================================

```
$xmlPath = "D:\Users\admin\Desktop\Report.xml"
$date = Get-Date -UFormat %m/%d/%Y

if ( ! ( Test-Path $xmlPath ) )
{
    # Create The XML
    $global:xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($xmlPath,$Null)
    $global:xmlWriter.Formatting = "Indented"
    $global:xmlWriter.Indentation = "4"
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Execution")
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ExecutedOn")
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Date",$date)
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Environments")
    Foreach( $c in $cEnvironments)
    {
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($c.Environment)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Red",$c.Red)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Green",$c.Green)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Blue",$c.Blue)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #end of $c.Environment
    }
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #end Environments

    $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ClEnv")
    Foreach( $c1 in $clEnv)
    {
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($c1.Environment)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("John",$c1.John)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Mike",$c1.Mike)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Alex",$c1.Alex)
        $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #end of $c1.Environment
    }
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #end ExecutedOn
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #end execution
    $global:xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument() #end document
    $global:xmlWriter.Finalize
    $global:xmlWriter.Flush()
    $global:xmlWriter.Close()
}
else
{
    here I need to append the data in existing xml with the same above info but with different value
}
```

======================================================================
$cEnvironments $clEnv variables are array and having related data. Now I need to re run the script next day and check if the file is already exist. this is I am doing with if command. if it is already exist then using "else" I need to append the data in existing xml with the same above info but with different values under section "Execution" like given below

======================================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'?>
<Execution>
    <ExecutionStarted Date="2/19/2014">
     <Environments1>
        <Colors Red="21" Blue="14" Green="18" />
    </Environments1>
    <Environments2>
        <Names John="21" Mike="14" Alex="18" />
    </Environments2>
</ExecutionStarted>
***<ExecutionStarted Date="2/20/2014">
     <Environments1>
        <Colors Red="2" Blue="56" Green="76" />
        <Colors Cyan="31" Brown="32" Black="54" />
    </Environments1>
    <Environments2>
        <Names John="45" Mike="63" Alex="97" />
    </Environments2>
</ExecutionStarted>***
</Execution>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could some one please help me in appending xml in above code

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.  Had to make a couple of changes, since $date wasn't defined, but see if this does what you need it to:

```
# Set the File Name
$filePath = "e:\Report2.xml"

# Create The Document
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($filePath,$Null)

# Set The Formatting
$xmlWriter.Formatting = "Indented"
$xmlWriter.Indentation = "4"

# Write the XML Decleration
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

# Set the XSL
$XSLPropText = "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'"
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", $XSLPropText)

# Write Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Execution")

# -- Begin New Code #1 --

# $date doesn't seem to be defined, setting it so it looks like your results...
$date=1

# -- End New Code #1 --

# Write the Document
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ExecutionStarted")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Date",$date)
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Environments1")
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Colors")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Red","21")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Yellow","14")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Green","18")
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()# Closing Colors
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing environments1


$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Environments2")
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Names")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("John","21")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Mike","14")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Alex","18")
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()# Closing Name
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing environments2


$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing executionstarted

# -- Begin New Code #2 --

$date++

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ExecutionStarted")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Date",$date)
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Environments3")
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Colors")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("blue","21")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("black","14")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("cyan","18")
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()# Closing Names
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing environments3

$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing executionstarted

# -- End New Code #2 --

# Write Close Tag for Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing RootElement

# End the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()

# Finish The Document
$xmlWriter.Finalize
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Comment: I am sorry. I may not be able to explain properly. below again I explaining hope this is understandable.

Comment: Please find the changes I have explain in above question section. let me know if it is not understandable